# PHP session var strange value through AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, session

my code is a bit messy so I'll try to explain to you in words:

I have this index.php page that shows a random file from my files table in my database. People have the opportunity to rate these files by clicking on notes that open "vote.php" through a small AJAX pop-up.

Now here's the problem. On index.php I pull the ID from the database and output it:

```
$_SESSION['file_id'] = $file_id;
echo $_SESSION['file_id'];
```

But when I open the vote.php pop-up and write:

```
session_start();
echo "SID="; echo $_SESSION['file_id'];
```

The value is not the same! What could cause this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you called session_start() in your index.php ?

Comment: Yes. Should I maybe close the session at the end of index.php though?

Comment: Do you know where "SID" is coming from ? Is it like the prev/next value ? Is there a logical way to have "SID" from what `$_SESSION['file_id']` should have been ?

Comment: @user You don't have to close the session.

Comment: Certain broken browsers *cough*IE*cough* don't allow AJAX requests to access the session cookie; damned if I know under what circumstances. Do you have the same session ID on the PHP side for both requests? You might want to sniff on the connection and make sure the AJAX request is sending the same session cookie as the main page.

Comment: "my code is a bit messy so I'll try to explain to you in words" I stopped reading after this. I want to recommend you this book about refactoring: http://martinfowler.com/books.html#refactoring Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

Without fixing this specific problem, I don't think `$_SESSION` is needed here.

Can't you open `vote.php` with

```
vote.php?file_id=xxxx
```

You just need to add the variable in the URL when you generate index.php.

No need for sessions here.

Comment: Yeah I think I'm going to rewrite it and do it like this. At first I thought of the sessions because I thought I would avoid people finding the "trick". But I check their IP or their username (if logged) in voted.php anyway, so it's unnecessary.

Comment: If want to avoid people to vote too ofter you can allow only one vote every x seconds using session (IP is not that good : there can be a lot a people for just one IP, think of a router in a company).

Comment: Interesting, but what's the maximum of seconds I can put? My goal would be to allow only one vote per lifetime.

Comment: Well the IP is changing so if you allow vote for unregistered users there is no way to do it...either only allow registered users for put a big constant, a few hours maybe...

Comment: Yeah I'm aware the IP can change, but it's not the case for everyone. Currently I store the IPs in a table but the x seconds thing will be way lighter. Thanks!

Comment: Not for everyone but for the majority.

Answer (score 0):

You shall pass sessions variables to your AJAX requests in the form of (javascript code):

```
enquiry.php?' + session_name + '='  + session_id + '&vote=whaevere_you_want&foo=bar
```

Where **session_name** and **session_id** are javascript local variables obtained via AJAX initalizer to fetch them from a php script which is capable of providing them via PHP functions:

```
session_name()
session_id()
```

respectively